# Android WiFi Aware App: Error When Creating Multiple Networks with Pixel 3a XL

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an Android app that utilizes the [WiFi Aware API](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/wifi/wifi-aware). In my app, every device needs to act as both a publisher and a subscriber of the same service. I am testing this on three Pixel 3a XL devices.

The issue I'm facing is that I can successfully discover all devices from each phone, but I can only create two single networks between two phones. When I attempt to establish the third and fourth network between phones, i think i hit a [resource limit of data paths](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/aware/AwareResources#getAvailableDataPathsCount()).

I encounter the following error message:

`10:35:42.326 WifiAwareDataPathStMgr   E  WifiAwareNetworkFactory.releaseNetworkFor: networkRequest=NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1012, [ Transports: WIFI_AWARE Capabilities: NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN Specifier: <WifiAwareNetworkSpecifier [type=0, role=1, clientId=57, sessionId=79, peerId=227, peerMac=<null>, pmk=<null>, passphrase=<non-null>, port=0, transportProtocol=-1]> Uid: 10232 RequestorUid: 10232 RequestorPkg: com.example.final_test_wifiaware UnderlyingNetworks: Null]`

I have tried to only have one publisher and two subscribers but i got the same error.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPeCl.png)

Comment: can you link to any doc that states that you can establish multiple WifiAware connections at once? imho thats not possible, physical WiFi module is one and can execute one task at once: can be connected to one WiFi network, one WiFiAware device, acting as one hotspot. these features are excluding eachself, you can't stay connected to some AP and in the same time act as AP by self (hotspot)

Comment: In the diagram i showed in the post the case 1 works, i can act as a publisher and subscriber to the same service and create two networks between them, this is the logs 

https://imgur.com/a/qtAUqjq

And if i run "wifiAwareManager.getAvailableAwareResources().getAvailableDataPathsCount()" i get 2, so 2 data path per device, but its weird that i get a cache error and not a path limit error

Comment: i run the same thing on a pixel 6 i had and the data path count is 8 for that, so probably a physical limitation of the device, but still i dont get the cache error, this is the source code of the log message https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/aware/WifiAwareDataPathStateManager.java;l=971;drc=2f3b8ec38adc04d36441174cbe9c55dbdaa2c04d